# Introduction of Control Variable in Toda and Yamamoto Procedure

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality, eviews

I have conducted Granger Causality test between the prices of futures index and price of individual stocks using Toda and Yamamoto Procedure. Now i got a suggestion to include some business life cycle indicating index like S&P 500 index as a control variable to make my model more robust and avoid the issue of classical omitted variable problem.

I am bit confused about the steps to include the control variable in my test using EViews platform. Any hints and guidelines will be appreciated.

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: I simply don't know how to introduce control variable in the VAR equation and in the EViews program.

Comment: I mean when using Toda and Yamamoto Procedure

Comment: I don't know how to do it in EViews, but in a VAR model you can easily include exogenous variables. Just add them on the right hand side in the VAR equations.